# Xeround MySQL Cloud Database Backend Connection Refused with Heroku but connects with MySQL WorkBench 5.2

Tags: mysql, wordpress, heroku, xeround

I've a WordPress Blog Website running on a Heroku Cloud Web-space (Stack - Cedar) whose back-end is at Xeround Cloud MySQL Database (10 MB free DB Plan, only 1 MB used till now). Every thing was **well configured & running well from 2 days**, until when today i visited the Heroku Website showed the "Internal Server Error", on Checking the Heroku logs, i found that now the Xeround Database Connection was Rejecting always. I've checked the Database Connectivity with MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE with same DB Credentials written on the WordPress Config file, it got connected & Queried well.

> > Now I am unable to find the way to rectify the problem. How should I find what's going wrong with the Heroku to Xeround DB Connection. (DB Space is still 8 MB+ available & Heroku logs not providing any info why Connection got rejected.)

Comment: Have you tried contacting Xeround Support? xeround.zendesk.com

Comment: @clieu : They (Xeround) contacted me after watching this question here on stackoverflow.com. (Don't know how they got me here??)

Thanks for suggesting!